# How to convert NSString to NSDate in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am building an application where I need to convert The NSString to NSDate. I have googled and found a lot links of SOF mentioned below -

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-
   back-again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)
2. [Convert NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640929/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate)
3. [Converting can NSString to NSDate format in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539502/converting-can-nsstring-to-nsdate-format-in-objective-c)

I had used the answer given there but the problem I still facing is explain below step by step.

1. I had taken NSString *StringDate = @"01:00:00"; // I have declared time in the NSString variable.
2. I used the conversion method that mentioned in above link and stored the converted value to the NSDate variable.
3. When I am NSLog the NSDate variable. I am get "19:30:00" in my logcat. While the expected result should be "01:00:00".

Here is one of the code I am using

```
NSString *dateString = @"01:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: This issue has been discussed *so* many times here.  Please make more of an effort to search before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -(NSString *)geTimeFromString:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",string];
        NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
        NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
        NSString *stringFromTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
        return stringFromTime;
    }
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain me what is the meaning of ''en_US_POSIX" in above code ??

Comment: From the [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) - " when working with fixed-format dates, set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines"

Comment: my application is crashing

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the correct date, but printed in a different timezone. I posted a longer explanation here:

[Unexpected value from NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378)

BTW: In

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

`[[NSDate alloc] init]` is completely meaningless, because you assign an instance of `NSDate` in the very next line.

Comment: How to set TimeZone in that So I can get the correct answer.

Comment: Logging is always done in UTC+0. This *is* the correct answer. `NSLog()` is for logging and nothing else. If you want to convert the date into a string according to a specific time zone, use an instance of `NSDateFormatter` and log the (string) result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to convert NSString to NSDate :-

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDate
{
    NSString* dateStr = @"20/05/2015";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    return date;
}
```